# Produce infinite distinct limit sets from an original set on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Limit set** Suppose that $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, The limit set of $P$
$$P':=\{\mathrm{all\ the\ limit\ points\ of\ }P\}.$$
Now we ask for a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$A^{(1)}=A',A^{(2)}=(A^{(1)})',A^{(3)}=(A^{(2)})',\cdots,A^{(n+1)}=(A^{(n)})',\cdots$$
are distinct$(n=1,2,\cdots)$.

---

The idea occured to me was that the limit set of $\{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\}(m,n\in \mathbb{N}^+)$ is $\{\frac{1}{n}\}(n\in\mathbb{N}^+)$, so I tried $A=\{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}|a_i\in\mathbb{N}^+,n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$, only to find that $A'=[0,+\infty)$, whose limit set is the same as itself.

This is just so tricky to find such a set which is able to carry out the limit-set operation infinitely without repetitiveness. I wonder if anyone can help me on it. Thank you in advance! Any idea would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You could use countable ordinals in the order topology instead, these all embed into $\Bbb Q$ via Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you! Could you please elaborate a bit? I don't quite get it, especially "Cantor's theorem""countable ordinals"...

Comment: Look up ordinal numbers if you don't know them. Cantor has shown that every countable ordered set embeds into $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henno Brandsma has suggested one approach. Here is another; I’ll leave it to you to verify the details.

Let $A_0=\{0\}\cup\left\{2^{-k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$; clearly $A_0^{(1)}=\{0\}$, and $A_0^{(2)}=\varnothing$.

If $X\subseteq\Bbb R$ and $a,b\in\Bbb R$, let $a+bX=\{a+bx:x\in X\}$.

Let $A_1=\{1\}\cup\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(1+2^{-k}+2^{-k}A_0\right)$. If you draw a sketch, you’ll see that $A_1$ squeezes a copy of $A_0$ into each of the intervals

$$\left[1+2^{-k},1+2^{-k}+2^{-(k+1)}\right]$$

for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$. And you can show further that $A_1^{(1)}=\{1\}\cup\left\{1+2^{-k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, $A_1^{(2)}=\{1\}$, and $A_1^{(3)}=\varnothing$.

Continue in this fashion, recursively constructing sets $A_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ by letting

$$A_{n+1}=\{n+1\}\cup\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(n+1+2^{-k}+2^{-k}A_n\right)$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$; $A_{n+1}$ squeezes a copy of $A_n$ into each of the intervals

$$\left[n+1+2^{-k},n+1+2^{-k}+2^{-(k+1)}\right]$$

for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$. The construction ensures that $A_n^{(n+1)}=\{n\}$ and $A_n^{(n+2)}=\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus, the set $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ has the desired property.